# go-git checkout failing with reference not found

Tags: go, go-git

I'm just starting to use the go-git library and so far it looks very promising.
However, I'm trying to do a basic checkout of an existing branch and it is failing with "reference not found".
I have a simple repository, with several branches but one is "main" and another is "testoffmain".
Cloning, pulling and fetching the github repo work without issues.

Getting a hash for the branch seems to work fine as well:

```
        repo, err := git.PlainOpen(localGitRepo)
        w, err := repo.Worktree()

// Clone, Fetch, Pull all work, when I'm on the main branch

        headRef, err := repo.Head()
    newHashRef := plumbing.NewHashReference("refs/heads/testoffmain", headRef.Hash())
    hashRef := plumbing.NewHash(newHashRef.String())
    fmt.Printf("HashRef: %s", hashRef.String())   // Successfully displays the hash

        // Returns a valid hash
    revision := "origin/testoffmain"
    revHash, err := repo.ResolveRevision(plumbing.Revision(revision))
    fmt.Printf("HashRef: %s\n", revHash.String())

        // Checkout fails with "reference not found"
    referenceName := plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/heads/testoffmain")
    err = w.Checkout(&git.CheckoutOptions{
        Branch: referenceName,
        Force:  true})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s:  Checkout: Cound not open local repository, Error: %s\n", project.LocalRepo, err)
        return err
    }
```

I've search around, and oddly can't find this simple usecase, so I'm assuming I'm doing something basic wrong.
I'm using github.com/go-git/go-git/v5 v5.5.2

I've tried a variety of options in

```
   referenceName := plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/heads/testoffmain")
   referenceName := plumbing.ReferenceName("testoffmain")
   referenceName := plumbing.ReferenceName("origin/testoffmain")
   referenceName := plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/origin/testoffmain")
   referenceName := plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/remotes/origin/testoffmain")
   referenceName := plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/remotes/testoffmain")
```

As I test, I tried copying .git/refs/remote/origin/testoffmain to .git/refs/head/testoffmain and I can the checkout to work, but then other issues occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the referenceNames as below:

```
    refs, _ := r.References()
    refs.ForEach(func(ref *plumbing.Reference) error {
        if ref.Type() == plumbing.HashReference {
           fmt.Println(ref)
        }

        return nil
    })
```

See official [link](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/src-d/go-git#Repository.References).

And then we can use it for checkout:

```
    w, err := r.Worktree()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    err = w.Checkout(&git.CheckoutOptions{
        Branch: plumbing.ReferenceName("refs/remotes/origin/" + branchName),
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err, branchName)
    }
```

where `branchName` is the name of the git branch you want to switch

Comment: Thank you for the response, and sorry for the delay. When I try your suggestion, and then I run a "git branch" in powershell, I see "* (no branch)".

Comment: are you allowing checkout in cloneOptions?